# Java- Malformed packet

Tags: java, networking

I have a Java program that I am using to receive PDUs that are being sent over a network. The program will currently receive every PDU that is sent over the network- store their information in a set of ArrayLists, and then broadcast the information about each PDU that it's received back out over a different network.

While running my program, I am also using Wireshark to view information about the network traffic.
Although some of the PDUs that my program is broadcasting over the network appear 'normal' (i.e. they are displayed in Wireshark in the same format that most of the other PDUs are displayed- which aren't being sent by my program), for some reason, some of the PDUs that are sent by my computer display lines such as `218 Discover- NewRequest [Malformed Packet]`

It seems that these 'malformed packets' are the PDUs that have been sent when an exception has occurred- but since I have the necessary exception handling code in my program (the handled exceptions will just display a message to the user stating that an exception has occurred and why), shouldn't these packets also be sent 'normally' the same as all of the others?

Comment: When you say you have error handling in place, do you mean you that these PDU's should not ever be sent if there is an error? If so, can we see some code, its very hard to diagnose errors without it.

Comment: No- the PDUs will be sent over the network just the same, but I wouldn't have thought that they would actually hold any data- since an exception has occurred, and so the function that would have been executed hasn't happened- only an error message displayed to the user. I am just guessing that this is what the `malformed packets` are (the information displayed in Wireshark for each of the malformed packets states "Exception occurred)- I could well be wrong, but I couldn't think of anything else that they could be.

Comment: Having read up about malformed packets a bit more, i read that it is possible for Wireshark to incorrectly view some packets as 'Malformed'. What are you seeing at the packet destination? If not is it possible that whatever is causing the error is only part making into the PDU, hence making it 'Malformed'